# I2C timing issues on Linux

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, yocto, i2c

I am currently implementing a device in Linux using Yocto and I am having issues with the I2C timing, namely interrupt latency and inter byte delays.

My system is using Linux built on Yocto (FSLC Wayland with XWayland 3.1 imx8mm-var-dart ttymxc3) on a Variscite VAR-SOM-MX8MM-MINI board with a symphony interface board. I have the I2C devices setup on the board and have created custom hardware with three SC16IS750 devices on them. They work fine when I have the FIFO enabled on the devices. However due to a limitation of the chip I can only get a interrupt with four bytes with the FIFO on, I have asked NXP if there is a way of using the FIFO with single byte interrupt trigger. However the system I am interfacing to needs single byte notification and retrieval, this works as a single byte but takes around 8.5mS to retrieve the byte from the buffer. If I have multiple bytes coming in, then the buffer is quickly overwritten before I have retrieved the data and end up with only the last byte.

I hooked up my Saleae to the I2C port and I see that I have a 900us delay from the interrupt to the first start bit, then I have 300 to 600us delay between each byte in the I2C message, thus killing my chances of retrieving multiple bytes.  The standard driver for the SC16IS7XX (Jon Ringle version) only deals with the FIFO implementation and requests a number of registers before retrieving the data. Which should be OK if the latencies weren't so large. I don't want to start hacking the standard driver if I can help it.

Image showing the delays on a typical I2C integration.

So the [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7EQUn.png)

So the question I have is can the latency of the interrupt be decreased and how do I get rid of the inter byte latency in the I2C message, these seem particular unnecessary.

i have no experience apart from this project in Yocto, but I am an Embedded Development Engineer with over 20 years of experience in bare metal embedded development.

I am testing this by running CAT < /dev/ttySC1 to activate the chip and monitoring using the Saleae not sure if this is causing any issue.

Any help would be appreciated.

Glenn

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about micro-controller programming without showing any code to debug. [ask] and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
  I think there is a micro-controller stackexchange shown at the bottom of this page. Or possibly you want the electronic engineering stack.

Comment: This is clearly a question about Linux and its driver which usually is on stackoverflow. However, this is way more complex than a simple programming question. I can see a few optimizations you could do in sc16is7xx_port_irq but I'm not sure this would be enough.

Comment: The best choice you have is to: a) make sure you have a dedicated (!) CPU core to serve IRQs for your device (yes, modern CPUs in modern multi-tasking OS won't help until you have really RT properties out of it); b) increase speed of communication (1Mbps or higher); c) replace I²C UART to SPI; d) enable DMA; e) switch to RT Linux (it will improve., but maybe not too much in comparison to steps a-d). And the best, just do in an MCU which is connected to the host by USB or so, and which will do the preliminary work of gathering and handling data.

Comment: Hi Rob, this is definetly a Linux issue, if I was runing a micro to do this it wouold be sorted by now.

Comment: Hi @AlexandreBelloni what kind of optimisations, I have thought about editing the driver code to do away with the majority of the irq and just request the byte I know is in the buffer, there seems to be a lot of overhead to just get the data. However if the I2C driver was not inserting unecessary delays then I think the standard driver should work. What suggestions would you have for speeding up the latency on the I2C interrupt, 900uS seems a bit long on a quad core running at 1.8GHz. I was exoecting 10s of useconds for the ISR latency.

Comment: Hi @0andriy, I would have no idea on how to dedicate a CPU to handle interrupts. I have tried the I2C bus running to it's max, the issue actually gets worse if I run the bus at 400KHz, this is the max for the I2C chip. The most optimal was actually running at 200KHz, this had an interbyte delay of around 300uS. I have considered a dedicated CPU to handle the comms and I would have more control on storing bytes and running a single byte storage. I was hoping that there was a simple solution to remove the interbyte delays as they are not necessary for the chip or for Linux to run.

Comment: Look for _interrupt affinity_ settings. As I said, the best way is to connect external MCU and do this task exclusively there. Modern CPUs (in multitasking environment) can’t really serve UART, b/c UART needs too much attention, especially one connected via another slow and unpredictable bus.

Comment: The long inter-byte gaps have SCL low, which I guess is due to clock stretching by the I2C slave. (It *could* be being stretched by the I2C master, but that seems unlikely for a general purpose I2C master controller.)

Comment: Hi @Ian Abbott, thanks for that, I did look at that and convinced myself that the slave was not clock stretching, once the Ack is there the slave de-asserts it's SDA line (to logic 1) releasing the master to control the SCL line. Also there is nothing in the datasheet for the SC16IS7X indicating it does clock stretching. I have queried NXP anyway.

Comment: The only suspicious thing regarding clock stretching is that the SC16IS740/750/760 data sheet appears to show clock stretching in Figure 19 during interrupt servicing by the receiver.

Comment: @Ian Abbot it does show that, but the word from NXP is that clock stretching isn't part of the chips capability.

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like we are stuck with the repsonsiveness of the I2C as it is, the board manufacturer and NXP indicate that the response is as good as it gets. It may get faster depending on what is happening and conversly it may get slower. I am going to try and switch to SPI for the SC16IS7XX as the transfer method seems to be a bit quicker. The joys of getting Yocto to behave will start again.

Answer (score 0):

I am using an i.MX7D SoM and i can confirm that I2C communication has some jitter between byte transfer because it is implemented in a simple for loop in [i.MX Linux driver](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.18.10/source/drivers/i2c/busses/i2c-imx.c#L1114). If your transfer can use DMA i2c_imx_dma_write() of i.MX driver, you will not have any jitter in the I2C full frame but surely the next DMA based I2C transfer will have much overhead in time to start it again.

From i.MX7D, NXP started to provide heterogeneous SoC, it means there is a real-time co-processor inside i.MX7 and 8 (Cortex-A + Cortex-M). You can run a FreeRTOS code in it, and it could be better to use I2C transfers/communication in Cortex-M real-time capabality. In this case Linux needs to just waiting any data stream from it.